# Bash script to rename files to ensure the dash has spaces on both sides

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I am trying to rename files with a dash in the name to ensure the dash has spaces on both sides.

Example:

```
My- File.txt
My-File2.txt
My -File3.txt
```

should be

```
My - File.txt
My - File2.txt
Me - File3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using extglob:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *-*; do
   mv "$file" "${file/?([[:space:]])-?([[:space:]])/ - }"
done
```